# Periodicity of sine function $f(x) = \sin(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, periodic-functions

I know that the real function of sine

$$  f(x) : \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} \\
\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \, x \mapsto f(x) = \sin(x) $$

has a period of $2\pi$. I've tried to derivate it this way but I get a contradiction.

So a function $f$ is periodic if it verifies  $$ f(x) = f(x+T) $$

for some period $T$. So setting the equation

$$ \sin(x) = \sin(x+T)  $$

And since it is true for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then it must hold for $x = 0$ so:

$$ 0 = \sin(T) \implies T = n\pi , n = 0,1,2,...  $$

What's wrong with this?

Comment: You are affirming the consequent. If $T$ is a period, then $\sin(T)=\sin(0)$. But $\sin(0)=\sin(T)$ does not imply that $T$ is a period for $\sin(x)$.

Comment: You should also check for all other $x$, including $x=\frac\pi2$:

$$\sin \frac\pi2 = 1 = \sin\left(\frac\pi2 + T\right) \implies T = ?$$

What is the minimum positive $T$ that would work for all $x$?

Comment: So the thing is that, since I'm looking for  some $T | f(x) = (x + T) ~\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, I can't assume that the equation is true for a particular $x$?

Comment: If you want to prove that $\sin$ is convergent you need to start with a defintion.

Comment: What you have demonstrated is this:   

$$T\text{ is a period of }\sin x \implies T \in \{n\pi \mid n \in \Bbb Z\}$$
(Note: negative integers $n$ also give solutions to $\sin T = 0$.) But you are concluding that 

$$T \in \{n\pi \mid n \in \Bbb Z\} \implies T\text{ is a period of }\sin x$$

which is a different statement, and of course is false. Only half the members of that set are periods.